# jQuery carousel hide next and prev on first and last slide

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm very new with jQuery and I use this jQuery carousel. I don't want to use any plugin. But I want to ask how can I  hide next button, when I am on first slide and how can I hide next butto, when I am on last slide.

here is demo

http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/24/

here is jQuery code

```
$(function(){
var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
var clickCount = 0;
var canClick = true;

 itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin

//Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);

//Place the child elements to their original locations.
refreshChildPosition();

//Set the event handlers for buttons.
$('.btnNext').click(function(e){        
    if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(6)").text()!=14) {
        if(canClick) {
            canClick = false;
            clickCount++;
            //Animate the slider to left as item width 
            carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
                left : '-='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
                canClick = true;
            });
        }
    }
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
    if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(0)").text()!=1) {
        if(canClick){
            canClick = false;
            clickCount--;
            //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
            lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
            lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);

            lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);             
            //Animate the slider to right as item width 
            carousel.finish(true).animate({
                left: '+='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                canClick = true;
            });
        }
    }
});

function refreshChildPosition(){
    carouselChild.each(function(){
        $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
    });
}
```

});

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnPrevious">Previous</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnNext">Next</a>
<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you post your HTML too? Sorry - just seen JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/67/

```
$(function(){
var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
var clickCount = 0;
var canClick = true;

itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin

//Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);

//Place the child elements to their original locations.
refreshChildPosition();

//Set the event handlers for buttons.
$('.btnNext').click(function(e){      
    if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(6)").text()!='14' ) {
         $('.btnPrevious').show();
        if(canClick) {
            canClick = false;
            clickCount++;
            //Animate the slider to left as item width 
            carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
                left : '-='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
                canClick = true;
            });
            if ($(".carousel").find("li:eq(7)").text()=='14'){
              $('.btnNext').hide();  
            }
        }
    } 
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function(){

    if($(".carousel").find("li:eq(0)").text()!=1) {
        $('.btnNext').show();
        if(canClick){
            canClick = false;
            clickCount--;
            //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
            lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
            lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);

            lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);             
            //Animate the slider to right as item width 
            carousel.finish(true).animate({
                left: '+='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                canClick = true;
            });
            if ($(".carousel").find("li:eq(0)").text()=='1'){
              $('.btnPrevious').hide();
            }
        }
    } 
});

function refreshChildPosition(){
    carouselChild.each(function(){
        $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
    });
}
```

});

Comment: thanks. Are you know how can I make prev and next just with another style when they are on first and last slide, not to hide.